# May I ask on MS a question about how to explain Quantitative Easing side effects to kids?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

I would like to ask this question on MS:

> "How would you explain to kids what happens when a Central Bank prints
>   more money? It's simple to explain that it saves the banks and the
>   States by their huge debts, because it lends them the new printed
>   money, but what are the side effects of this on the economy?
>
> - inflation, but why?
> - the currency devaluates against other currencies? If yes why?"

BTW: I would like this to be explained to me too, but almost in the same way you would explain it to a kid.

---

EDIT: maybe it was obvious why I'm asking here if it's possible to ask such a question on MS. The reason is that I suspect it might not be an acceptable question because it's an economic question. Actually I would like to understand the QE side effects to make previsions of where to invest money, but I think it's quite useless to add to the question *"I would like to understand the QE side effects to make previsions of where to invest money"* just to avoid the question to be closed.

Comment: I like the question.  Framed as understanding the news and market, it certainly applies as a risk factor to regular investors

Comment: @MrChrister: thanks, but can I ask it or will it be closed? By Reading this http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/392/why-cant-we-ask-questions-about-economics-here-is-there-a-place-to-ask-questi and this http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/505/why-was-a-question-about-bank-runs-closed I don't know anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economics  - They can exist.

I think you just to **not** make it very academic.  Try to phrase it around "As an investor, what does it mean and why do I care".  The fed printing money certainly has impact on a trader's portfolio and their expectations.

What the US is doing compared to what the EU is doing will have big impacts for folks who invest in foreign markets.

A person shouldn't invest if they don't understand.  I would say the fact that QE is/was such a big topic in the news means it isn't so academic anymore.